# iphone - view init issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, uitextview

I have come across a strange behavior...

In class A, at the `viewDidLoad` method I do:

```
b = [[B alloc] initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil]; //init the B class (declared as B* b)
[b setText:@"ABCDDEEE"]; //change the text of a UITextView in b
```

note that b's view is not shown until a button is pressed. However, when I press it and go to b's view, the text of the `UITextView` is still the "lorem ipsun" text

Once b's view is shown once, I can change the text.

Anyone know this issue and how to solve it??

Comment: Maybe your setText: method tries to set your text view's content, which hasn't been wired up yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behaviour. `initWithNibName`does not guarantee complete initialization before `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: is there a way to force it to load completely?

Comment: I don't think so.
You could call `[b setText:]` and store the value in a member of your controller. Then set the value of the member in your view's `viewWillAppear` from the member.

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSString `@property` in B. Set that property when you load `b`--not the .text property of a UITextView, but an NSString data object in the view controller. Then in B's `-(void)viewDidLoad`, set the UITextView's text property with the string you set.

NIB elements don't necessarily exist when the parent view controller first instantiates a new view controller, but you can talk to data fields and then load that data into the view hierarchy members in `-(void)viewDidLoad`.

Comment: That's exactly how I implemented it =)